# How to fix ajax problem: 500 Internal Server Error in laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I tried using ajax to fetch my data from database and display it in my blade without refreshing it but when I applied the same steps to fetch different data for the other blade i get this error :

> POST http://localhost:8000/barangay/fetch 500 (Internal Server Error)
>   jquery-3.3.1.js:9600.

Here is the code that needs fixing:

This is my blade:

[image]

Here is my ajax script:

[image]

Here is my router to fetch the barangays that belonged to the selected city:

[image]

Here is my code in my controller to get the data:

[image]

and here in here is the output (**error :returns nothing**):
[image]

Comment: Can you provide us the error message? 500 (Internal server error) is a little bit difficult to debug.

Comment: go the the network tab and check the response from ajax

Comment: This should not be a question, no one can help.

Comment: You can click that error to view the specific error.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses the CSRF token in post request, so you required to add header in your ajax request something like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
```

for more more details you can use https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf

Comment: CSRF has been added in the data value as _token. Doesn't seem CSRF as a problem.

Comment: @lizeshakya data values are different & header is different, you should add the token in the header section.

Comment: it did not work @VaibhavSinghal, I got the same error.

Comment: @jane go to network tab... share the details for the particular request.

Comment: @jane try to log the error in app/Exceptions/Handler.php it will give you can idea about the error

Answer (score 0):

In addition to checking for the CSRF token as a POST parameter, the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware will also check for the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` request header. You could, for example, store the token in an HTML `meta` tag:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then, once you have created the `meta` tag, you can instruct a library like jQuery to automatically add the token to all request headers. This provides simple, convenient CSRF protection for your AJAX based applications:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

> By default, the `resources/js/bootstrap.js` file registers the value
>   of the `csrf-token` meta tag with the Axios HTTP library. If you are
>   not using this library, you will need to manually configure this
>   behavior for your application.

Comment: I have this in my blade inside my form {{ csrf_field() }} is this okay?

Comment: @jane nope... you should add this line into the header section

Comment: @jane you should add `meta` tag into the header section of your layout